# Installing Boost > 1.51 on Windows: substitute for Boost Pro?

Tags: windows, boost, installation

Ever since I started using boost on Windows with Visual Studio 2010 I just downloaded the binary package available on [BoostPro](http://www.boostpro.com/) as recommended by the boost documentation.  I'm currently at Boost 1.51 and would like to upgrade to Boost 1.55.  Now since BoostPro is no longer offering these packages, is there a substitute method to install the binary package or do I now need to build boost myself?

I see at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html the statement:

> The most reliable way to get a copy of Boost is to download
>   boost_1_55_0.7z or boost_1_55_0.zip and unpack it to install a
>   complete Boost distribution

Will this be equivalent to the Boost Pro binaries I used to download or will this still require building stuff?

Then I also found http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/.  Overall I'm confused.  Basically I'd like a simple installation like BoostPro used to offer if that is still available.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the binaries from http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/. They will work OK provided you pick up proper configuration of your compiler. Note that MSVC 2013 has some issues with some of Boost versions.

These binaries are not *guaranteed* to work because your compiler or STL can be customized in various ways. That is why Boost recommends to compile the package locally.